# Rails Stripe Js variable amount checkout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

The problem as best as I understand is that the stripe checkout modal is not being called and so the request goes through to my charges controller without the stripeToken having been set and thus throws up a source is empty error.

Here is a link to their setup tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/variable-amount-checkout

So I have literally copy / pasted their code while reading through and just simply modifed the minimum amount. I have had an error with the api-key however I got past that problem.

Here is a look at my error:
You have passed a blank string for 'source'. You should remove the 'source' parameter from your request or supply a non-blank value.

```
Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => @amount,
      :currency => 'usd',
      :source => params[:stripeToken],
```

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"long code...", "amount"=>"6", "stripeToken"=>""}

The modal does not appear before this error at all. I suspect that somehow the checkout modal js is just simply not being called by the donate button event handler.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
  locale: 'auto',
  name: 'Ragnar\'s Redoubt',
  description: 'One-time donation',
  token: function(token) {
    $('input#stripeToken').val(token.id);
    $('form').submit();
  }
});

$('#donateButton').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#error_explanation').html('');

  var amount = $('input#amount').val();
  amount = amount.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/\,/g, '')

  amount = parseFloat(amount);

  if (isNaN(amount)) {
    $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Please enter a valid amount in USD ($).</p>');
  }
  else if (amount < 1.00) {
    $('#error_explanation').html('<p>Donation amount must be at least $1.</p>');
  }
  else {
    amount = amount * 100; // Needs to be an integer!
    handler.open({
      amount: Math.round(amount)
    })
  }
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

I am a javascript noob but I don't see how handle.open() opens the checkout script right above. var handle does not call it either so what I am missing here?

Comment: I am getting the same error in my Rails app.  What is maddening is that the very first time I set everything up according to the Stripe documentation, everything worked fine.  But it failed every time after that.

Comment: You may want to try my answer below. If you can get on their IRC channel there are lots of great individuals that can really help debug what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a risk of answering my own noob question...

I got wonderful help from the #stripe irc channel on freenode.

I somehow miss-typed  even though I typed it correctly here?

So I was correct it was a modal not showing up problem, which as the helpful individuals on #stripe said, "open chrome developer tools and check console to see if there are any javascript errors".

There was and it led me directly to a spelling error. So +1 #stripe, +1 chrome tools.